# Replace New with other solution?

Tags: java

This code has lot of trouble for my AIR 2.0 Native process which I tried to launch Java from AIR application, then the Java.exe terminate itself in the Windows Task manager, I found that `new MidiTest()` was the caused. Is there a better solution for new instance?

```
 public static void main(String[] arg) {
   BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   while (!(speed.equals(speed_stop))) {
    try {
        speed = in.readLine();
        if(!(Global.newPlayer.equals("1"))){new MidiTest();}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception while reading the input. " + e);
    }
   }
 }
 private MidiPlayer player;

 public MidiTest() {
  System.out.println("Start player");
  // /*
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the only other option for creating a new instance of your class would be using reflection, which is a much more obscure and error prone choice than `new`. It should not be used unless one really needs to. And even that is loading the class and calling the object's constructor in the end, exactly the same way as `new`.

I suspect the problem lies somewhere in code you haven't shown to us. Does `MidiTest` have any (`static` or nonstatic) initializer blocks? Is that `println()` statement really the only code in its constructor?

Of course, it helped if you traced down what is the exact error/exception causing the termination and where exactly does it originate from :-)

Answer (score 0):

**There is no alternative to new.**

This is the only way to instantiate an object.  Even if you use reflection, you're still calling the constructor.  You need to track down the problem.  Find the exact exception that's being caused, and the exact line number, and then see what you need to do to fix that problem.

I can see that you didn't provide a complete copy of your code.  There's an open comment before the close brace, and it's not right.  So that means we can't help you any further with the information we have.